# App cannot enable Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-storage

My primary app id has a very limited set of options in the Cloud Console for some reason. Notably, I cannot access "APIs & Auth" to enable GCS. Here's the menu I see on the left side. Billing is enabled and my app is actively serving traffic. Other apps I create work just fine.

Here is what I see:

```
Overview
Permissions
Settings
Support
Preview App Engine
Preview Cloud Datastore
BigQuery
```

Here is what I expect (and see from other projects):

```
Overview
APIs & auth
Permissions
Settings
Support
Preview App Engine
Compute Engine
Cloud Storage
Preview Cloud Datastore
Cloud SQL
BigQuery 
Cloud Development
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I did not see "Google Cloud Storage" on my Cloud Console. The solution I got from Google a while back was the following:

1. Sign in to AppEngine under the account that **created** the App. (via appengine.google.com)
2. Click "Application Settings" under the Administration Settings
3. There you should find a button to enable Google Cloud Console, under a section called **Cloud Integration**

This should tie your application as you expect it.

Comment: That doesn't work, already did that. :-( Under Cloud Integration it says:

Cloud Integration
Create a Google Cloud project for this application.
The project was created successfully. See the Basics section for more details.

And the id links correctly, but not with GCS.

Comment: @DavidByttow I had the same problem as well, the key was to do it when logged in as the project owner. You may need to get in touch with Google on this one :/

Comment: Yes. And am definitely logged in as project owner. My contact at Google is on it, just not being resolved as quickly as I'd like. ;-)